# what exactly happen in jvm when i create an object in java?

Tags: java, jvm, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

To my understanding if i am writing

```
Car a3=new Car()
```

This statement will create a handle named `a3` in jvm stack with all its properties in JVM heap.
IF this is correct i am wondering how call by value works.
So, if i create a method `checkMethod(Car c)` and call it by saying `checkMethod(a3);`
suppose our car is

```
public class Car{
   int a=0;
   public int getpar(){
       return a;
   }
}
```

in `checkMethod` i try to access a `using a3.a = 5;` so i changed the value of `a3.a`
it will show me in the calling class as well as it was pointing to the same fields that jvm created in the heap.

But when i do `a3= null;` in the calling method and go back again in the method from which i was calling 
`checkMethod(a3)` and try to see this object it is not null?
Why it behaved differently as compared to property of object that is a???

Comment: Imagine a3 (and all variables) as being pieces of paper with addresses written on them. When you pass a variable to a method you **copy** the **address** on to a new piece of paper (bacuse java is pass-by-value). When you set that variable inside the method to null you scribble out the address on the piece of paper. But the original remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 checkMethod(a3);
```

Pass a copy of a value which is a reference to object instance of Car

Inside method...

```
a3.a = 5
```

Using a3, modify object instance of Car which is identified by a3 ( which is a copy of original a3).

```
a3 = null
```

Set the reference to null ( copy)

When this happens, only the copy you passed to your method will point to null. But the original a3 still points to your object instance of Car.

Answer (score 1):

`Why it behaved differently as compared to property of object that is a?`

Because Java is (pure) `call by value`. You cannot manipulate the value of the parameter within the callee context. You always gets a local copy in the calling context.

Answer (score 0):

On method calls, Java passes a copy of the reference.

So when setting a3 to null, it only set its copy of the reference to null and the other copies that are stored else where.

Answer (score 0):

The whole trick is this: Java passes **references** by **value** :)